# Issue with sending multiple messages on Python Lan Chat App

Tags: python, multithreading, chat, message

I have pasted below the server and client side made for a lan chat app, which allow users to send messages in a general chat room and also allowing them when they double click on a specific user to send a private message in a separate window. My problem is when I have two private windows open at the same time and send a message to two different users. One of the private window gets stuck and the message does not send.

I have tried to debug the recipient in the server side for when send the message and everything seems to be fine, I guess the problem is somewhere in the private window def but I don't know where.

thanks...

Server side:

```py
import socket
import threading
from datetime import datetime


class ChatServer:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.server_socket.listen(10)
        self.clients = {}
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        now = datetime.now()
        current_date = now.date()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
        self.data_ora = str(current_date) + "/ " + current_time

    def start(self):
        print(f"Server : {self.ip}:{self.port} la: {self.data_ora}")
        try:
            while True:
                client_socket, client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
                username = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
                self.lock.acquire()
                self.clients[username] = client_socket
                self.lock.release()
                print(f"{username} connected: {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} la: {self.data_ora}")
                threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(username,)).start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Closing")
            self.server_socket.close()
            for client_socket in self.clients.values():
                client_socket.close()

    def handle_client(self, username):
        client_socket = self.clients[username]
        try:
            while True:
                message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message.startswith("QUIT"):
                    print(f"{username} disconnected")
                    break
                elif message.startswith("LIST"):
                    self.send_user_list(client_socket)
                elif message.startswith("@"):
                    # Split message to find recipient and message body
                    recipient, message_body = message.split(" ", 1)
                    recipient = recipient[1:]  # Remove the "@" symbol
                    self.send_private_message(recipient, f"{username} {message_body}")
                else:
                    self.send_message_to_all_clients(f" {self.data_ora}-{username}: {message}")

        except ConnectionResetError:
            pass
        except:
            print(f"{username} disconnected")
        finally:
            self.lock.acquire()
            del self.clients[username]
            self.lock.release()
            client_socket.close()
            self.send_user_list_to_all_clients()

    def send_message_to_all_clients(self, message):
        self.lock.acquire()
        for client_socket in self.clients.values():
            try:
                client_socket.send(f"{message}\n".encode('utf-8'))
            except:
                pass
        self.lock.release()

    def send_user_list(self, client_socket):
        self.lock.acquire()
        user_list = "USERS," + ",".join(self.clients.keys())
        try:
            client_socket.send(user_list.encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            pass
        self.lock.release()

    def send_user_list_to_all_clients(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        user_list = "USERS," + ",".join(self.clients.keys())
        for client_socket in self.clients.values():
            try:
                client_socket.send(user_list.encode('utf-8'))
            except:
                pass
        self.lock.release()

    def send_private_message(self, recipient, message):
        self.lock.acquire()
        if recipient in self.clients:
            try:
                self.clients[recipient].send(f"@{message}\n".encode('utf-8'))
                print(f"Message: {message} for {recipient}")
            except:
                pass
        self.lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChatServer('192.168.0.104', 8080).start()
```

Client side:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox
import socket
import threading
import os


class ChatClient:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.username = os.getenv('username')
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client_socket.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        self.client_socket.send(self.username.encode('utf-8'))
        self.gui()

    def refresh_users(self):
        try:
            self.get_online_users()
            self.root.after(5000, self.refresh_users)
        except:
            self.on_closing()

    def gui(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title(f"ChatApp: {self.username}")
        self.root.geometry(f"{800}x{380}")
        self.root.configure(bg='#CAF3D8')
        self.root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.root.after(5000, self.refresh_users)
        self.private_messages = {}
        self.ziua = tk.StringVar()

        now = datetime.now()
        self.current_date = now.date()
        self.current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
        self.data_ora = self.current_date, self.current_time
        self.ziua.set(str(self.current_date))


        self.messages_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='#CAF3D8')
        self.messages_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n', padx=13)

        self.message_h_label = tk.Label(self.messages_frame, text="Messages", bg='#CAF3D8', font=("", 8, "bold"))
        self.message_h_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.scrollbar_y = tk.Scrollbar(self.messages_frame)
        self.scrollbar_y.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.scrollbar_x = tk.Scrollbar(self.messages_frame, orient='horizontal')
        self.scrollbar_x.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')

        self.msg_list = tk.Listbox(self.messages_frame, height=15, width=100, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_y.set,
                                   xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_x.set, bg='#ECF9F5', font=("Times New Roman", 10, ""))
        self.msg_list.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.scrollbar_y.config(command=self.msg_list.yview)
        self.scrollbar_x.config(command=self.msg_list.xview)
        self.msg_list.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_y.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_x.set)


        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='#CAF3D8')
        self.bottom_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')

        self.message_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_frame, text="Message:", bg='#CAF3D8', font=("Times New Roman", 8, ""))
        self.message_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.message_entry = tk.Entry(self.bottom_frame, width=80)
        self.message_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.message_entry.bind('<Return>', self.send_message)

        self.send_button = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="Enter", command=self.send_message)
        self.send_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2)

        self.del_button = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="X", command=self.del_messages, bg='#ebc034', width=2)
        self.del_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5)

        self.user_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='#CAF3D8')
        self.user_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='n')

        self.scrollbar1 = tk.Scrollbar(self.user_frame)
        self.scrollbar1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')

        self.users_label = tk.Label(self.user_frame, text="Connected users:", bg='#CAF3D8', font=("", 8, "bold"))
        self.users_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.message_h_label = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.ziua, bg='#CAF3D8',
                                        fg='#727473', font=("", 8, ""))
        self.message_h_label.place(x=530, y=1)

        self.users_list = tk.Listbox(self.user_frame, height=15, width=20, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar1.set, justify='left')
        self.users_list.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.users_list.bind("<Double-Button-1>", lambda event: self.open_private_message_window(self.users_list.get(tk.ACTIVE)))

        self.get_online_users()

        self.receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_messages)
        self.receive_thread.start()

        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def del_messages(self):
        self.msg_list.delete(0, tk.END)  # sterge textul din widget

    def open_private_message_window(self, user):  # deschide fereastra mesaje private

        if user == self.username:
            messagebox.showwarning("Attention!", "You can not chat with yourself!")
            return

        if user not in self.private_messages:
            self.private_messages[user] = []

        self.private_window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.private_window.title(f"Private message cu {user}")
        self.private_window.geometry(f"{420}x{300}")
        self.private_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='chat_icon.png')
        self.private_window.wm_iconphoto(False, self.photo)
        self.private_window.lift()

        message_frame = tk.Frame(self.private_window)
        message_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        scrollbar_y = tk.Scrollbar(message_frame)
        scrollbar_y.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        self.private_msg_list = tk.Listbox(message_frame, height=15, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set, font=("Times New Roman", 10, ""))
        self.private_msg_list.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        scrollbar_y.config(command=self.private_msg_list.yview)

        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self.private_window)
        bottom_frame.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

        message_label = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="Message:")
        message_label.pack(side='left')

        self.private_message_entry = tk.Entry(bottom_frame, width=50)
        self.private_message_entry.pack(side='left', padx=5)

        send_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Send",
                                command=lambda: self.send_private_message(user, self.private_message_entry.get(), self.private_msg_list))
        send_button.pack(side='left', padx=5)

        self.private_message_entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.send_private_message(user, self.private_message_entry.get(), self.private_msg_list))

        self.private_messages[user].append(self.private_msg_list)

        self.private_message_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.private_message_entry.focus_set()
        self.mesaj_inchidere = self.private_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: self.clear_private_messages(user))

    def clear_private_messages(self, user):
        # Sterge mesajele private
        self.private_messages = {}
        # Inchide fereastra de mesaje private
        self.private_window.destroy()

    def send_private_message(self, user, message, private_msg_list):
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
        full_message = f"{self.username} {current_time}: >>>{message}"
        print(full_message)
        self.client_socket.send(f"@{user} {full_message}".encode('utf-8'))
        self.private_msg_list.insert(tk.END, full_message)
        self.private_message_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.clear_private_messages(user)

    def get_online_users(self):
        try:
            self.client_socket.send("LIST".encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            self.on_closing()

    def receive_messages(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message.startswith("USERS"):
                    self.update_user_list(message[6:])
                elif message.startswith("@"):
                    username, message = message[1:].split(maxsplit=1)
                    if username in self.private_messages:
                        self.private_msg_list.insert(tk.END, message)
                        self.private_window.lift()
                        self.private_window.attributes("-topmost", not self.private_window.attributes("-topmost"))
                    else:
                        self.open_private_message_window(username)
                        self.private_window.lift()
                        self.private_window.attributes("-topmost", not self.private_window.attributes("-topmost"))
                        self.private_msg_list.insert(tk.END, message)
                else:
                    self.root.deiconify()
                    self.root.attributes("-topmost", not self.root.attributes("-topmost"))
                    self.msg_list.insert(tk.END, message)
                    self.msg_list.see(tk.END)
            except:
                self.on_closing()
                break

    def send_message(self, event=None):
        message = self.message_entry.get()
        self.message_entry.delete(0, tk.END)  # sterge textul din widget
        if message.strip() != "":
            try:
                self.client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            except:
                self.on_closing()
        self.message_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def update_user_list(self, user_list):
        self.users_list.delete(0, tk.END)
        users = user_list.split(",")
        for user in users:
            self.users_list.insert(tk.END, user)

    def on_closing(self):
        self.root.iconify()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChatClient('192.168.0.104', 8080).gui()
```